# How to restrict access to a folder but still access a safe.html file in that folder in nginx?

Tags: nginx, server, directory, active-directory

Lets say there is a folder in /var/www/html/admin, so i want to restrict access while maintaining access to /var/www/html/admin/login.html in nginx. How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quite understand what do you want to achieve, what other content you have in that folder and who would have an access to that folder, but you can do something like

```
location = /admin/login.html {}
location /admin {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Hmm similar thanks, i m trying this now, should i need to apply in nging.conf ? under  http or under events @IvanShatsky

Comment: I used the thing you told. However, index.html and login.html both are accessible.

Comment: @DipeshSunrait Do you reload nginx after applying changes to configuration? Do you have other locations related to `/admin`?

Comment: Deleting your answer and service nginx restart doesnt give error, having nginx cofig same as this cause error : https://imgur.com/gallery/9HJ5owo

Comment: @DipeshSunrait You should include this inside the `server` block.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UuDE4tl this too gives me error

Comment: @DipeshSunrait Files where the `server` blocks are defined located inside the `sites-enabled` directory.

Comment: hey bro still the error, the sites-enabled/default config was something like this when it works https://imgur.com/a/2OYgv6j however this doesnt work https://imgur.com/a/2rSnFa2 plz help

Comment: @DipeshSunrait Do not comment the default `location / { ... }` block. Put this two locations after it. Do not miss the `{}` part.

Comment: Ok, i didnt understand what did you meant by `Do not miss the {} part.`. i made the default same as previous and did service nginx restart and it works however  when i add lines given by you like this : https://imgur.com/a/tYnFFRm it brings error

Comment: @DipeshSunrait In my answer I had `location = /admin/login.html {}` line, you added to your config `location = /admin/login.html`. Is it really so hard to understand what I mean?

Comment: IT WORKS BUT A PROBLEM. https://imgur.com/a/UKnt5v5 . Login.html and index.html both are acessible, I modified your answer , there is `{` missing in `location /admin`. I added it. I ran service nginx restart and it works . however index.html is still accessible

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
root@kali-linux:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#

Comment: @DipeshSunrait And again you can't just copy/paste my answer correctly. Am I used the `=` sign at the second location?

Comment: @DipeshSunrait And you are right that I missed the `{` on my second location, fixed it in updated answer.

Comment: FINAL. https://imgur.com/a/mb7AYXO . Without adding `{` gives error at `service nginx restart` however  adding `{` makes both index.html and login.html visible /accessible

Comment: Any idea? I m really feeling crazy right now. This time copied pasted properly. https://imgur.com/a/MZ8b9xY

Comment: @DipeshSunrait This time everything should be ok, `/admin/login.html` should be accessible while `/admin`, `/admin/index.html` etc shouldn't. Do you have some other `server` blocks under the `sites-available` directory?

Comment: THANKS BRO YOU HELPED ME A LOT